# IVideoWindow::put_WindowStyle throwing "No such interface supported"

Tags: c#, windows-ce, directshow

I've got a C# control wrapped around the DirectShow libraries.  Though I'm not certain it's relevant, I'm running on Windows CE 6.0R3. When trying to play a WMA audio file using the control, the following code throws an exception of `"No such interface supported"`:

```
m_graph = new DShowGraph(mediaFile);
m_graphBuilder = m_graph.Open();
m_videoWindow = (IVideoWindow)m_graph.GetVideoWindow();

if (m_videoWindow == null)
{
    // this is not hit
}

try
{
    m_videoWindow.put_WindowStyle((int)(WS.CHILD | WS.VISIBLE | WS.CLIPSIBLINGS));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // I end up here
}
```

The `Open` call looks like this (error handling, etc. trimmed):

```
private IGraphBuilder _graphBuilder;

internal IGraphBuilder Open()
{
    object filterGraph = ClassId.CoCreateInstance(ClassId.FilterGraph);
    _graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)filterGraph;
    _graphBuilder.RenderFile(_input, null);
    return _graphBuilder;
}
```

The GetVideoWindow call simply looks like this:

```
public IVideoWindow GetVideoWindow()
{
    if (_graphBuilder == null)
        return null;
    return (IVideoWindow)(_graphBuilder);
}
```

Strangely, this all works just fine with the same control DLL, same application and same media file when run under Windows CE 5.0.

My suspicion is that it might have something to do with the fact we're playing an audio-only file (checking to see if the same problem occurs with a video file now), but I'm not overly versed in Direct Show, so I'd like to understand exactly what's going on here.

One of the large challenges in debugging this is that I don't have the failing hardware in my office - it's at a customer's site, so I have to make changes, send them and wait for a reply.  While that doesn't affect the question, it does affect my ability to quickly follow up with suggestions or follow on questions anyone might have.

**EDIT1**

Playing a WMV file works fine, so it is related to the file being audio-only.  We can't test MP3 to see if it's a WMA codec issue becasu the device OEM does not include the MP3 codec in the OS due to their concerns over licensing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph's `IVideoWindow` is nothing but forward to underlying `IVideoWindow` of video rendering filter. With audio only pipeline you don't have the video renderer (obviously) and `IVideoWindow` does not make much sense. The interface is still available but once you try to call methods, there is nothing to forward, hence the error.

Comment: Yeah, that was my suspicion.  Oddly it all works in CE 5.0, indicating that the underlying Direct Show implementation must have changed between CE 5.0 and 6.0.  For now I'm just looking at the media file's extension (WMA or MP3) to determine if it's audio-only (is there a way to ask the graph is a video renderer exists?) and skipping the `IVideoWindow` initialization if I think it is.

Comment: I would say that catching the `E_NOINTERFACE` error where you get it now is the easiest to see if video renderer is there. Only video renderers support it (on desktop some video renderers do render video and do not support this interface). Yes you can enumerate filters and query `IVideoWindow` interface directly from them, I am just not sure if it is worth bothering.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm now catching the exception and setting a "no video renderer" flag so I can skip the remainer of the IVideoWindow initialization code.