# COMException occurred - Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)) when i trying invoke IVideoWindow::put_Owner() method

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

I'm working with DirectShow framework and trying to capture video from my webcam. Using the "ComImport" and "Guid" attributes, I import COM interfaces. When accessing the put_Owner() method of the IVideoWindow interface, I get an exception. In other interfaces, methods are called and return the S_OK result. Why can't it find a method with the given name?

Interface declaration:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComImport]
[Guid(Constants.IVideoWindowGuid)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IVideoWindow {

    [PreserveSig]
    public HResult put_Owner(IntPtr owner);
}
```

I call the method as follows:

```
hResult = _videoWindow.put_Owner(Window);
if(hResult != HResult.S_OK)
    throw new Exception(hResult.ToString());
```

I tried to capture a video in a console application, but there was no result, so I decided to create a WPF application from which I get a HWND handle. According to my logic, the video should be displayed in the WPF window, but the put_Owner method cannot be found.

Thanks

Edited.

`_videoWindow` is a member of the `IVideoWindow` interface (the declaration is described above), which in my case is a private field.

```
private IMediaControl _mediaControl;
private IMediaEventEx _mediaEvent;
private IVideoWindow _videoWindow;
```

Initialization occurs as follows:

```
_graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)(new FilterGraph());
_captureGraphBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)(new CaptureGraphBuilder2());

_mediaControl = (IMediaControl) _graphBuilder;
_mediaEvent = (IMediaEventEx) _graphBuilder;
_videoWindow = (IVideoWindow) _graphBuilder;
```

For comparison, the methods of the objects `_mediaControl` and `_mediaEvent` are called successfully and return HRESULT S_OK result.

Comment: The error message is accurate, the actual interface does not have a method named put_Owner().  It has a *property* named Owner.  Declare  it as `IntPtr Owner { get; set; }`.  Documenting properties as methods with get and put prefixes is not terribly uncommon but only works in client code that uses the interface, can't work in the interface declaration.

Comment: @HansPassant
I guessed that it was the properties, but I didn't dare to try. Thanks for the answer! I tried using the property and caught an exception (0x80020005 DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH). In C++, LONG_PTR is used, in C# I use IntPtr, I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Don't post code as images, post it as text so it can be easily copied

Comment: @Maku Thank you! I edited question and replace images to code block

Comment: Your code seems wrong (set_Owner vs put_Owner), what's _videoWindow, where does it come from? Is it a native object? How is it defined? etc. Please show a minimal reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier
I edited question and added a sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IVideoWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/control/nn-control-ivideowindow) is a *dual* interface, meaning it supports an `IUnknown`-derived interface and an [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) interface.

When you declare this on an IDispatch interface:

```
[PreserveSig]
public HResult put_Owner(IntPtr owner);
```

It means the interface is supposed to declare an "put_Owner" *named* method with a parameter. This is not the case as the IVideoWindow definition in IDL format (you can see that with the [OleViewer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer) from Windows SDK) is:

```
dispinterface IVideoWindow
{
    ...

    [id(0x60020016), propput]
    void Owner([in] LONG_PTR rhs);
  
    [id(0x60020016), propget]
    LONG_PTR Owner();

   ...
}
```

Which means if you want to declare it as an IDispatch interface in C#,  you must do this:

```
[ComImport, Guid("56a868b4-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IVideoWindow
{
    // the name "Owner" here *must* match idl's name
    IntPtr Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Note the name is important, but this could work too:

```
[ComImport, Guid("56a868b4-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IVideoWindow
{
    // the name here doesn'the match idl's name so the DispId *must* match idl's pidl
    [DispId(0x60020016)]
    IntPtr Blah { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can declare it using the IUnknown-derived version, but in this case you must stick exactly to the binary contract, which would be something like this:

```
// note this InterfaceIsIUnknown here
[ComImport, Guid("56a868b4-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IVideoWindow
{
    // you *must* declare methods in same order as they are defined in .idl or .h to match IVideoWindow vtable
    // or use the VtblGap trick
    void _VtblGap0_26(); // skip 4 (IDispatch) + 22 IViewWindow methods

    // note: names are irrelevant here, it's a binary contract
    [PreserveSig]
    int put_Owner(IntPtr owner);

    [PreserveSig]
    int get_Owner(out IntPtr owner);
}
```

Note here I used the [VtblGap trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564635/can-i-simplify-method-signatures-i-am-not-using-in-a-comimport) to avoid declaring all methods I don't need.

Another possibility, probably the most simple way, is just to create a COM reference to the "ActiveMovie control type library", located in %windir\System32\quartz.dll. In this case, you can use it like this:

```
var gm = new QuartzTypeLib.FilgraphManager();
var win = (QuartzTypeLib.IVideoWindow)gm;
win.Owner = ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! 

```
int hr = _videoWindow.put_Owner(Window);
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

System.InvalidCastException: "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @Alkamal - Absolutely, but that's completely another problem which is specific to the COM object in question (DirectX Show, FilterGraph, IVideoWindow). .NET InvalidCastException corresponds to COM error E_NOINTERFACE. Even using 100% C/C++, you'll get that error when calling put/get_Owner. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7f5a7d9d-a17f-42b6-aecf-20cfb1d5b61f/enointerface-when-i-used-putowner-of-ivideowindow?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035918/ivideowindowput-windowstyle-throwing-no-such-interface-supported

Comment: I apologize for the bad comment, I didn't quite understand the UI of stackoverflow.
It seems like I realized my mistake, thank you very much for your help!